# What does the word "its" in the phrase "its implications" refer to?

Tags: word-meaning

The text in question is:

> "In addition to posing philosophical problems in its own right, moral
>   reasoning is of interest on account of its implications for moral
>   facts and moral theories."
>   (source: Moral Reasoning By Henry S.
>   Richardson)

I have three questions to ask:

1. What does the word "its" in the phrase "its implications" refer
   to?   I think that the word its refers to philosophy's but I am not
   sure.
2. What does the word implications here mean?   I understand the
   literal meaning of the word but I can't figure out what it means in
   the context.
3. What does the phrase "of interest on account of its implications"
       mean? I think the phrase means "an interest in figuring out its
       implications" but I am sure about that either.

Could you please help me clarify it?  Thank you always.

Comment: Even if we take **its** there to be a *cataphoric* reference to "moral reasoning", the sentence is a poorly constructed sentence. That becomes clear when we flip the clauses: "Moral reasoning is of interest on account of its implications ... **in addition to** posing philosophical problems in its own right..."

Comment: Compare this analogue: *The restaurant is of interest on account of its unconventional menu **in addition to** hiring award-winning chefs.*   We need another possessive to turn **hiring** into a gerund to have parallel nominals:  ... in addition to **its** hiring award-winning chefs.  [unconventional menu...its hiring award-winning chefs]

Comment: *In addition to **its** posing philosophical problems in its own right, moral reasoning is of interest on account of its implications for moral facts and theories.*

Answer (score 2):

1) "Its" refers to "moral reasoning" just several words ahead of it.

2) "Implications" means something that follows from it, something that is influenced by it. In this case, "its implications" is talking about how moral reasoning **impacts** what we then consider to be moral facts, and influences our moral theories. E. g., a certain way of moral reasoning can modify some existing theories.

3) It means that moral reasoning is interesting for us (is an interesting subject of study) *because* of how it impacts moral facts and theories. Since it influences moral facts and theories, it is interesting to research how exactly this influence comes to be. "On account of" means "because".

Answer (score 2):

1) Both of the "its" refer to "moral reasoning"

2) implications is a very vague word in this context, and without seeing a bit more of what the author had to say its precise meaning is obscure. I suppose he argues that moral reasoning affects what we consider to be moral facts and moral theories, both of which are, I assume, technical terms.

3) The author claims that moral reasoning is interesting because of the way it affects the, other two aspects of the subject.